# Iterate through all pages and output in a single html file

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I need to output a node (ID 2334) including sub-nodes into a single document to print them later.

How can I load all sub-nodes and output them beneath the main node?

**Update**

I'm using Drupal 8.

I want to combine all subsites for a given node into a single page.

By sub-nodes / sub-sites I'm referring to the navigation tree.

The key goal is to have a printable version of a whole website section.
Like a category where it combines all related articles into one page.

**Update 2**

I created a custom page controller and managed to get an array of "sub-nodes":

```
$subnodes = [];

$tree = \Drupal::menuTree()->load('internal', new \Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuTreeParameters());
foreach ($tree as $item) {
    if ($item->link->getRouteParameters()['node'] == $node) {
        foreach($item->subtree as $subitem) {
            $subnodes[] = $subitem->link->getRouteParameters()['node'];
        }
    }
}

var_dump($subnodes); // array of ids
```

I'm now wondering how render the given nodes?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it with a custom controller:

```
public function exportAll($node) {

    $node = (int)$node;
    if ($node < 1) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException($node . 'not available');
    }

    $subnodes = [$node];

    $tree = \Drupal::menuTree()->load('internal', new \Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuTreeParameters());
    foreach ($tree as $item) {
        if ($item->link->getRouteParameters()['node'] == $node) {
            foreach($item->subtree as $subitem) {
                $subnodes[] = $subitem->link->getRouteParameters()['node'];
            }
        }
    }

    $nodes = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($subnodes);
    return $build = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node')->viewMultiple($nodes);

}
```